# How to make a TD background color from-to, in percentages?

Tags: html, css

I have a table, and I want to give a background color, in percentabe, but not fill it.
I could do the inverse of it:

```
<table border="1" width="100%''">
<tr>
  <td style="width: 50%; background-color: red;" class="bg">....</td><td style="width: 50%"></td>
</tr>
</table>

.bg
{
    background-size: 10% 100%, 25% 100%;
    background-image: url('https://www.hrenko.hu/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Untitled-design-5.png'), url('https://www.hrenko.hu/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Untitled-design-5.png');
    background-position: left top, right top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;    
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jarhbdLc/

see those two google images? Well I want something like that - but the inverse of it! I want this background image to fill from 10%-25% AND NOT 0-10%, 25%-100%! How to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `linear-gradient`

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, transparent 10%, red 10% 25%, transparent 0) no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

---

Applying the fix.

```html
<table border="1" width="100%''">
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 50%; background: linear-gradient(to right,transparent 10%, red 10% 25%, transparent 0) no-repeat;" class="bg">....</td>
    <td style="width: 50%"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```